# Dozer Mapper is not mapping directly

Tags: java, reflection, dozer

I have a SourceClass with following parameters as:

```
class SourceClass{
   public Integer a;
   public Integer b;
}
```

And a DestinationClass as:

```
class DestinationClass {
   public Integer a;
   public Integer b;
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

    SourceClass src= new SourceClass();
    src.a= 1;
    src.b= 2;

    DestinationClass dest = mapper.map(src, DestinationClass.class);

    System.out.println(dest.a  + "  " + dest.b);
}
```

The last line of the code is showing as **null   null**, now I have tried by giving the **getter/setter** as well but didn't worked, I finally got the output by specifying **@Mapping** annotation giving the name of the variable to map like @Mappinf("a"), but as you see my variable names are same, can't dozermapper do it by itself?Because [here](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#auto-property-name) it is written that it maps the same named variables automatically.

Comment: Without the Annotations do you have a Dozer Mapping XML file?

Comment: Why should I have that, I kep't the names same,  why it is needed, you are conveying the same thing, what will be the difference in annotating and keeping ans XML mapping and loading it.?

Comment: I was just asking the question for my own sanity... why do you have src.a = "a"; when src.a is an Integer?

Comment: Ok I have changed the question, now check

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first of all either change SourceClass variables to Strings or change src.a and src.b values to be Integers.

Secondly you need to have getters and setters in both SourceClass and DestinationClass because dozer relies on them regardless if the variables are public or private.

The following solution works:

```
public class SourceClass{
private Integer a;
private Integer b;

public Integer getA(){
    return a;
}

public void setA(Integer a){
    this.a = a;
}

public Integer getB()
{
    return b;
}

public void setB(Integer b){
    this.b = b;
}
}

public class DestClass{
    private Integer a;
    private Integer b;

    public Integer getA(){
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Integer a){
        this.a = a;
    }

    public Integer getB(){
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Integer b){
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();

        SourceClass src = new SourceClass();
        src.setA(1);
        src.setB(2);

        DestClass dest = mapper.map(src, DestClass.class);

        System.out.println(dest.getA() + "  " + dest.getB());
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Now, although I gave your answer +1, but its not at all relevant,  where it is written that it relies on getter/setters, when I am making it as public, and if making getter/setter is the issue, how it is working when I am providing the @Mapping annotation.